# DMI Trend up/down Tr osc stoch

Tags: pine-script, sequence, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to calculate the trend direction and execute squares that are red or green depending on the stoch > ta.sma(stoch, Smoothing_period). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//@NooshQ First attempt at a complex indicator
    //Hours Total: 164
    //Trades missed: 7
    //Girl mad: 3
    //Hours wasted: 0
//@version=5
indicator("Trend Direction High timeframe", shorttitle="HTFT", overlay=false)

// Inputs
DMI_period = input.int(20, "DMI period", minval=1, maxval=100)
Smoothing_period = input.int(6, "Smoothing period", minval=1, maxval=100)
src = input(close, title="Source")

// Calculate True Range (TR)
tr = ta.tr(true)

// Calculate PlusDM and MinusDM
hiDiff = ta.highest(high, 2) - ta.highest(high, 3)
loDiff = ta.lowest(low, 3) - ta.lowest(low, 2)
plusDM = (hiDiff > loDiff) and (hiDiff > 0) ? hiDiff : 0
minusDM = (loDiff > hiDiff) and (loDiff > 0) ? loDiff : 0

// Calculate ATR using SMMA function
smmalen = input(20, "Length")

// Function for SMMA Calculation
smma(src, smmalen) =>
sma = ta.sma(src, smmalen)
smma := ta.valuewhen(true, sma, 1)
smma := smma ? ((smma * (smmalen - 1) + src) / smmalen) : sma

// Calculate ATR
ATR = smma(tr, DMI_period)

// Calculate PlusDI and MinusDI
PlusDI = 100 * smma(plusDM, DMI_period) / ATR
MinusDI = 100 * smma(minusDM, DMI_period) / ATR

// Calculate oscillator and smoothed oscillator
osc = PlusDI - MinusDI
stoch = ta.sma(osc, Smoothing_period)

// Determine Trend Direction based on comparison of stoch values
trnup = stoch > ta.sma(stoch, Smoothing_period)[1] ? 1 : 0
trndown = stoch < ta.sma(stoch, Smoothing_period)[1] ? 1 : 0

htft = trnup == 1 ? "Up" : trndown == 1 ? "Down" : ""

// Configure colors and shapes
upColor = color.new(color.green, 0)
downColor = color.new(color.red, 0)

// Plot columns
plot(htft == "Up" ? 1 : htft == "Down" ? -1 : na, style=plot.style_columns, color=htft == "Up" ? upColor : downColor)
```

Calculation of Smoothed Moving Averages:
The smma method is used to calculate the Smoothed Moving Average (SMMA) of a given source.
The SMMA is calculated using the sma function.
Calculates the True Range (tr) using the ta.tr function with true argument.
Calculates the plusDM and minusDM values based on the highest highs and lowest lows of the specified periods.
Calculates the ATR using the smma (Smoothed Moving Average) function defined in the script.
Calculates the PlusDI and MinusDI values as percentages using the smma function and the ATR.
Calculates the oscillator (osc) as the difference between PlusDI and MinusDI.
Calculates the smoothed oscillator (stoch) using the simple moving average (sma) of the oscillator.
Determines the color based on the comparison between the current stoch value and the previous stoch value.
Plots shapes and characters based on the color value.

I can't get values to appear on my chart so I struggle to determine what my issue is. I have gotten plots  but they were when I separated the data into individual segments and plotted them.

If you have any recommendations where I can find the help or if you can offer any help, your input is wanted. Thank you in advance <3@Noosh